# Is it possible to use custom annotations instead of @Named in top of @Provides?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, annotations, inversion-of-control, guice

Assume we want to `@Inject` Strings. I create the `Module`:

```
public class StringModule extends AbstractModule{
    @Provides
    String black() {
        return "black";
    }

    @Provides
    String white() {
        return "white"
    }
}
```

and now I ask for the injected value:

```
@Inject
private String wantWhiteHere;
```

Obviously Guice will throw an error because the binding is ambiguous. I know that i can get `white` if I use the `@Named` annotation like that:

```
public class StringModule extends AbstractModule{
    @Named("black")
    @Provides
    String black() {
        return "black";
    }

    @Named("white")
    @Provides
    String white() {
        return "white"
    }
}
```

and then:

```
@Named("white")
@Inject
private String iGotWhiteHere;
```

But what I want is this:

```
public class StringModule extends AbstractModule{
    @Black
    @Provides
    String black() {
        return "black";
    }

    @White
    @Provides
    String white() {
        return "white"
    }
}
```

.

```
@White
@Inject
private String tryingToGetWhiteHere;
```

**Is it possible?** When I do it the exception:

> A binding to java.lang.String was already
>   configured...

Is there anything anywhere that I can configure to achieve it?

My version of Guice is [4.2.3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.inject/guice/4.2.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use `@Qualifier`

Yes, it is possible. Make sure that you have the following declaration:

```
@javax.inject.Qualifier
@Target({ FIELD, PARAMETER, METHOD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface White { }
```

You can find [more info](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations) on Guice's official wiki.